# Alignment issue in the Activity -> answers tab

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, activity

There is an alignment issue in the **Activity -> answers** tab. The text in the bottom **deleted recent answers** doesn't applied with valid padding.

Inspecting on the text element, it has the class `recently-deleted { padding-top: 10px; }`, but it doesn't applied correctly.

> [image: Deleted Recent Answers]

Where as the text **deleted recent questions** in the **Activity -> questions** tab has the same class and it is rendering correctly.

> [image: Deleted Recent Questions]

Comment: Related for [mobile web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289565/339911)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is an error in the size of the div containing the `recently deleted answers` link.

Have a look at these images:

[image]
(click to enlarge.)

This is the problematic div with the `recently deleted` class containing the link. The size of this div is **1060 x 132.4** (I don't know which units are used here, maybe rem or em). Look how big this div is (highlighted in blue) and how far it overlaps with other elements. Also note that the padding is there (the purple bar, on top of the element highlighted blue).

---

Now compare that with the identical div on the questions page.

---

[image]
(click to enlarge.)

This the div containing the link to `recently deleted questions`. The size of this element is **1060 x 26.9**. As you can see, the div containing the link is the right size, and the padding is also in the right place.

---

It looks like the size of the problematic div is set wrong in the CSS. The HTML of the two elements is identical, so I can't see that the problem comes from there. If it is not in the HTML it must be in the CSS.

I can't find where the size of the div is set, though. Its size is not set through the `recently-deleted` class. The only instance of `recenly-deleted` in the CSS:

```
.recently-deleted {
    padding-top:10px
}
```

This does not set the size. I don't really know much about CSS, maybe someone who knows CSS will be able to find out where the size is set.

I hope this is helpful to anyone trying to troubleshoot.